# 'Execution Reverts' when sending ERC-20 token on Swift

Tags: erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, wallet-transfer, transferfrom

When I run this method in Swift, the transaction fails. And I get the following error in Polygon Scan Mumbai:

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted].

When I print allowance, it always prints as 0 even though I approve a certain value in the line above. Here's the [web3.swift package](https://github.com/Boilertalk/Web3.swift) I'm using. Also, here's the documentation from the [wallet provider](https://magic.link/docs/auth/blockchains/ethereum/ios#send-transaction) I'm implementing. Here's my [most recent transaction](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xcba55b52bacef1d0a8ba83dd4d777954b8394602492beec30a5b608f6223ba5c) on polygon scan mumbai.

```
func sendUSDCTransaction(web3: Web3){

    do {

        // Dummy ERC20 Contract for testing
        let USDCcontract = try GenericERC20Contract(address: EthereumAddress(ethereumValue: "0xfe4F5145f6e09952a5ba9e956ED0C25e3Fa4c7F1"), eth: web3.eth)

        let userAddress = try EthereumAddress(ethereumValue: "0x3ff4e98be04ba8c0d96a4b5ee6bd8d7ee834cbec")
        let senderAddress = try EthereumAddress(ethereumValue: "0x551Fa22d9722286dceA636516683B8B3b8a6aF0D")
        let contractAddress = try EthereumAddress(ethereumValue: "0xfe4F5145f6e09952a5ba9e956ED0C25e3Fa4c7F1")


        // Step 2: Get current USDC balance and Matic balance to check if user can do the transaction
        let balance = USDCcontract.balanceOf(address: userAddress)

        // Balance is a SolidityReadInvocation type, we can apply call function on it
        balance.call{ result, error in
            if let error = error{
                print("Error:", error)
                return
            }

            if let result = result{

                // Wei-to-ether conversion factor (1 ether = 10^18 wei)
                let conversionFactor = BigUInt(10).power(18)

                // Perform the conversion
                if let balanceInWei = result["_balance"] as? BigUInt {
                    // Divide the balance by the conversion factor to get the balance in ETH
                    let balanceInEth = balanceInWei / conversionFactor

                    // Print the balance in ETH
                    print("Balance in ETH: \(balanceInEth)")
                } else {
                    print("Invalid balance value or conversion failed")
                }

            } //: RESULT
            
        } //: BALANCE

        let approval = USDCcontract.approve(spender: contractAddress, value: BigUInt(20000))

        var allowance = USDCcontract.allowance(owner: userAddress, spender: contractAddress)
                  allowance.call{ result, error in
                    if let error = error{
                      print(error)
                    }
                    if let result = result{
                      print("Allowance: ", result) // Prints 0 currently
                    }
                  }

        let transaction = USDCcontract.transferFrom(from: userAddress, to: senderAddress, value: BigUInt(10000))

        transaction.send(nonce: nil, from: userAddress, value: EthereumQuantity(quantity: 10000), gas: EthereumQuantity(quantity: 34000), gasPrice: nil) {result, error in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }

            if let result = result {
                print(result)
            }
        }


    } catch {
        print(error)
    }



} //: FUNC SEND USDC TRANSACTION
```